# Apache Flink SQL: Reference guide for table properties

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm using the Flink SQL API with the sql client. I would like to know if there is a **reference guide for all available table properties** for a specific type/format-type?

For example i want to define a CSV source-table and in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connect.html#csv-format) it is written, that there is the option `format.allow-comments' = 'true` but then the client throws an error, that the option is not available.

Another example, from googling around i found the option `ìgnore-first-line`, but it is not in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your referenced document is legacy, in fact all table connector properties and format properties should be available from the document website:

table connector properties:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/#table-sql-connectors

table format properties:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/formats/

For example, the CSV format properties is here:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/formats/csv.html#format-options

Hope these information can help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But with the current filesystem/csv combination: Is it possible to skip the header of a CSV file? Or is the only possible option to ignore parsing errors but with the disadvantage of missing real parse errors in the data lines?

Comment: I think it's not easy to skip because current implementation is deserializing per record and the CSV format can be used with Kafka/FileSystem thus we're hard know which record is first. The workaround using `ignore-parse-errors` has the disadvantage you analyzed. But I think the requirement makes sense, we can create an issue to support this.